# Python web application works locally but crashes on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, web, python-requests

I have a web application which calls another web service, *convert2mp3* to be specific, I use python `requests` module to get the html response, however, the html which I obtain differ when I run it locally and on heroku.

I build the url the following way:

```
base_url = 'http://convert2mp3.net/en/index.php'
payload = {
    'p': 'call',
    'url': youtube_link,
    'format': 'mp3'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0)     Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0'
}

response = requests.get(base_url, params=payload, headers=headers)
```

Then I search for an `iframe` with a particular id in the html response obtained, using beautiful soup. Running this locally works as intended, but on heroku the html response obtained does not contain the `iframe`.

I also compared the response headers obtained

**Local**

```
{
  'Date': 'Sat, 27 Jan 2018 13:18:36 GMT',
  'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
  'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Last-Modified': 'Sat, 27 Jan 2018 13:18:35 GMT',
  'Set-Cookie': '__cfduid=d5165dcd0d27b292871b83ec3fe1e2c911517059115; expires=Sun, 27-Jan-19 13:18:35 GMT; path=/; domain=.convert2mp3.net; HttpOnly, WSID=14390776415a6c7c2b7ee98vmlgzp6yziAAEgZBkcm0ekzF14jra3463970b7614cb8e2ba0abd1eae870598; expires=Sat, 28-Apr-2018 19:18:35 GMT; Max-Age=7884000; path=/; domain=convert2mp3.net',
  'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0',
  'Pragma': 'no-cache',
  'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding, User-Agent',
  'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
  'Server': 'cloudflare',
  'CF-RAY': '3e3bffaea3c22df1-BOM',
  'Expires': 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT'
}
```

**Heroku**

```
{
 'Date': 'Sat, 27 Jan 2018 13:08:28 GMT',
 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'Last-Modified': 'Sat, 27 Jan 2018 13:08:27 GMT',
 'Set-Cookie': '__cfduid=d00205adb7be018693ab849649dab79cd1517058507; expires=Sun, 27-Jan-19 13:08:27 GMT; path=/; domain=.convert2mp3.net; HttpOnly, WSID=11414627405a6c79cbb6a99An8ctaOAsolaQuv30wiReUyhYCLTIU84ca82bf822fd1f79bbe5e90f7bc3135; expires=Sat, 28-Apr-2018 19:08:27 GMT; Max-Age=7884000; path=/; domain=convert2mp3.net',
 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0',
 'Pragma': 'no-cache',
 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding, User-Agent',
 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
 'Server': 'cloudflare',
 'CF-RAY': '3e3bf0d89641239c-IAD',
 'Expires': 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT'
 }
```

I noticed that *CF-RAY* differs in the response headers, running locally gives `xxxBOM` and on heroku gives `xxxIAD`, but I don't understand what they mean.

I understand that this is website specific, but would greatly appreciate if someone could help me understand why this happens.

Comment: BOM may be a [Byte-Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) therefore I think this may be related to encoding. Have you checked that?

Comment: How do I check it? Heroku's python environment is set to python3.6.4, so it should handle the encoding, right?

Comment: Actually, it was a wild guess and I am not sure CF-RAY pertains to encoding at all. I could think of issues with missing authorization cookie. Are you trying to authenticate to the site? You may have done it locally once and the cookie may be there but not on heroku.

Comment: No authentication is required for this site. I have done the same scraping on a different platform and worked as intended.